# How can I get the xserver to use my embedded display port monitor for the SDDM login screen? (Fedora 31)

Tags: fedora, xorg, multi-monitor, optimus

I have an optimus laptop with the HDMI output handled by the nvidia card and the embedded display port laptop monitor handled by the igpu. I want to be able to get my external monitor to be usable when it is plugged in, but I also want the login to display on the laptop monitor so that I can log in if there is no external monitor connected. There is no switch in the bios to disable optimus. I've done the following so far.

I've set my nvidia card as the primary GPU which lets me use my external monitor but creates other problems. Setting the nvidia card as the primary gpu is the  This is what my nvidia.conf looks like at the moment.

```
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "nvidia"
        MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
        Driver "nvidia"
        Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
        Option "SLI" "Auto"
        Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
        Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
        Option "MetaModes" "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "layout"
        Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection
```

The problem is that if there is nothing connected to the HDMI output, I can't log in through SDDM because the xserver wants to use the hdmi output connected to the nvidia gpu.

I've tried setting `Option "MetaModes" "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"` in my xorg configuration, but the xorg log says that the monitor DFP-1 is disconnected when the xserver is starting. [Here](https://pastebin.com/wcpfBSML) is my Xorg log to when it decides to use the external monitor for SDDM.

Does anyone know how to make this work?